# R - match and conditionally replace values in a data frame specific column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, replace, match

I saw a lot of similar questions but none of the answers have worked for me...
Here's my example data

```
company<-c("c1","c1","c2","c2","c2","c3","c3","c3","c4","c4", "c4")
subsegment<- c("Sub2","Sub3", "Sub1","Sub2", "Sub3", "Sub1","Sub2", "Sub3", "Sub1","Sub2", "Sub3")
values<-c(120,300,30,300,1800,10,96,277, 10, 400, 1100)
df<- data.frame(company,subsegment, values)

company.keys<-c("c1","c2","c3","c4")
company.description <- c("CocaCola", "Pepsi", "Boing", "Perrier")
lookup.company<- as.data.frame(company.keys, company.description)

subseg.keys<- c("Sub1", "Sub2", "Sub3")
subseg.description<- c("SoftDrink", "Snacks", "Other")
lookup.subseg<- as.data.frame(subseg.keys, subseg.description)
```

I have my original data frame df
I want to take the column 'company' and go search in 'lookup.company' to replace the keys with the description.
I know how to do it like this but I want a way that will use my lookup data frames:

```
 df$subsegment[df$subsegment == "Sub1"] <- "SoftDrink"
```

I tried but I get an error:

```
df %>%
mutate_at(subsegment, funs(ifelse(. %in% lookup.subseg$subseg.keys, lookup.subseg$subseg.description[match(., lookup.subseg$subseg.keys)], .)))
```

Error: Warning message:
`funs()` was deprecated in dplyr 0.8.0.
Please use a list of either functions or lambdas:

As I said, I know it has been asked before but none of the answers I saw seemed to work for me
I would like to use dplyr for the solution

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  left_join(rownames_to_column(lookup.subseg), c("subsegment" = "subseg.keys")) %>% 
  select(-subsegment, subsegment = rowname)

   company values subsegment
1       c1    120     Snacks
2       c1    300      Other
3       c2     30  SoftDrink
4       c2    300     Snacks
5       c2   1800      Other
6       c3     10  SoftDrink
7       c3     96     Snacks
8       c3    277      Other
9       c4     10  SoftDrink
10      c4    400     Snacks
11      c4   1100      Other
```